# Protractor hangs indefinitely when running hundreds of tests which takes more than 6 hrs to execute

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Protractor hangs indefinitely when running hundreds of tests which takes more than 6 hrs to execute. Sometimes(very rarely) we are seeing this behavior with jobs which take 30 minutes to complete as well.

We have configured jenkins job to run around 1000 tests with shardTestFiles enabled and max instances set to 10. Job always gets stuck saying 1 or 2 instances of webdriver still running.

If we connect to remote windows machine running tests, we will see 2 or 3 nodejs processes running with 0% CPU. On killing these process job completes without generating Junit xml.

Hanging issue is being seen consistently for the all the jobs which run for more than 6hrs. Please suggest solution for this.

Using windows 2012R2 and windows 2016 server machines with protractor 4.0.14, nodejs 6.9.5 and firefox 41.0.2. Seeing same behaviour with latest protractor 5.0.0 as well.

We have set below parameters in conf file:

1. jasmineNodeOpts:

   {
   showColors: true,
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000
   }
2. allScriptsTimeout: 600000
3. ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true
4. capabilities:

   {
   'browserName': 'firefox',
   'version': 'ANY',
   shardTestFiles: true,
   maxInstances: 10,
   }
5. browser.ignoreSynchronization: true
6. restartBrowserBetweenTests: true

Answer (score 2):

Since my response points out potential troubleshooting issues with what you have described above, I have included it in the answer portion.

1. I have a concern about your 1000 tests. This is a lot of e2e testing. Your tests are not meant to replace unit tests but to help give a positive signal that, as a user, the integration of services and Angular works. Also, e2e tests can be flaky because you are using drivers, the file system, browsers, and your Angular page under test. There are a lot of things that could just go wrong. I think you should turn off some of these tests, to find which tests that are causing flakes.
2. You are launching 10 instances in parallel. You should ask yourself if this is reasonable on the machine you are running. When launching a Firefox instance you are launching not just a new window but an entirely new instance of Firefox. I would suggest 3 or 4 at the max.
3. If you are setting `ignoreSynchronization` to true, then you must be handling the wait logic. If you are testing an Angular page, I would suggest leaving this as false to let the built-in `waitForAngular` to do its thing.
4. If your tests are indeed using the built-in `waitForAngular` logic (which Protractor does for you), this could be a flake. Increasing `allScriptTimeouts` is potentially masking some error in your test logic.
5. Restart browser between tests could cause significant delays. If you do not have to restart the browser, I would avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with anything in @cnishina's answer. This kind of behavior is typically due to a lack of cpu/ram on the machine. I would cut *way* back on the `maxInstances` and see if that is indeed the issue.